# Is there any window flag that can be controlled in the source code when the playwright is running?

Tags: cypress, playwright

In Cypress, you can use window.Cypress flag to change or add something in source code if Cypress is running. I wonder if the playwright has this flag. I want to intercept the websocket connection with run websocket-server in localhost so I need to change the endpoint URL if playwright runs in the code.

Example in cypress:

```
 const CYPRESS_SOCKET_URL = 'ws://localhost:4040';
 const socket = new WebSocket(
    window.Cypress
      ? CYPRESS_SOCKET_URL
      : ${config.WEB_SOCKET_URL}/websocket,
  );
```